# Find the matrix of the linear transformation on R 2 given by orthogonal projection onto line L containing the origin, angle theta with x-axis

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know where to even start on this one. Can someone help? I know that I need to find the projection matrix, but I cannot visualise this question.

Comment: Start by looking through the related (and basically duplicate) questions in the handy list at the right of the page.

Comment: See the image of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$

Comment: @irishSenthil Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that the projection onto a vector is given by

$$p = ax = a\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}$$

and in matrix form

$$p = ax = a\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}=\frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}b=Pb$$

refer to [Projections onto subspaces by MIT](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projections-onto-subspaces/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.2sum.pdf) for more details.